# Jenkinsx Nexus pod is going into "CrashLoopBackOff" state with "Login to nexus failed with the default password and the provided password secret file"

Tags: kubernetes, nexus, jenkins-x

I am trying to create a pipeline in Jenkinsx with Openshift cluster. The pipeline is successfully created but the springboot application build fails with "Nexus 401 authentication error".

So restarted all the pods under jx namespace. All the pods came up and running except the nexus pod.

The nexus pod is going into "CrashLoopBackOff" error with the following error:

```
"ERROR: Login to nexus failed. Tried both the default password and the provided password secret file"
```

I have observed that there is a nexus secret with the user and password details. I am unable to login to nexus dashboard using those credentials.

```
Credentials:
    username: admin
    password: hUw3nNQ!0eD,uuBS9qm9
```

I also suspect that the issue might be because of the exclamation in the password.

Please let me know if there is anyway to update the secrets to login to nexus.